# DnD 3.5 Character sheet in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools

I remember founding, a long time ago, a DnD Character sheet that was all based in excel, and calculating all your stats.

I'm looking for it again, and cant seem to find it anymore. Somebody would know where to find it?

Comment: The question is, does it need to be in excel? I believe I've seen a pdf version, without a change in graphics, that did the very same thing.

Comment: I've closed this as off topic given more recent policy updates regarding recommendation questions. Ostensibly this question is framed as a [tag:product-identification] which is fine and on topic, except "auto-calculating excel-based character sheets" is a wide subset of tools rather than a single identifiable tool, so this question became a "here is the auto-calculating excel-based character sheet I recommend".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For our D&D game I use the [Heroforge](http://www.nzcomputers.net/heroforge/) excel character sheet.  It covers a huge range of sourcebooks, variant rules etc.  You can also use it when you're playing to add buffs and temporary bonuses to save you the maths.

Comment: Good thing! And I also stumbled into this on my way, useful for dnd via skype. https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AiW4DB5E31LgdFNrN0ZldjBjVmcyYWJqcjlQREtXWnc&mode=public#

Answer (score 1):

Great Charts here! There is also some npc charts

http://www.stanford.edu/~rchilton/DnD/

Answer (score 0):

All the links here seems to be broken.

Here's a working one

http://nzcomput.brinkster.net/heroforge/default35.asp

Answer (score -1):

In 2003, the Dual-Class Character sheet was an excel based sheet that did the math for you... perhaps that is the sheet you are referring to?

We have evolved that sheet into what we call [The One Sheet](http://TheOnlySheet.com) over the past 10 years. It implements the full stacking rules, [can be used during play](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lErHyzSRN8o) or as a between-game printed sheet generator, and supports both D&D 3.5 and Pathfinder. The Core version is free to use, while the Plus version is a for-purchase product.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I'm pretty sure that using the product's name as a username is clear enough initial disclosure, but since usernames can be changed, I've edited the fact into the post for posterity.